# <td> tag inside table cell creates a line break in IE 7

Tags: html, css, jsp, internet-explorer-7, struts

I am working on an application in struts having jsp pages. IN IE 7 long sentence inside  tag creates a line break. Any idea what could be the problem?

Table is used to show records. When there is no record I show this sentence.

```
<tr><td colspan="6">No tags are currently stored in the database for this component</td></tr>
```

Here is the css code

```
table.outer_1 td { 

  border-right: 2px solid #CCCCCC; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC; 
  border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC; 
  border-top: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding:4px;
  max-width:250px;
  width:expression(250 + "px");
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

I think there is problem with `width:expression(250 + "px");`

Comment: @imran: in the source code do you see `<br>` tag?

Comment: Post your code if you want someone to help you out.

Comment: After writing this code my problem solved.

      ' <!--[if lte IE 8]>
         <style type="text/css" media="screen">
           table.outer_1 td {   width:expression(450 + "px") !important;  }
          </style>
         <![endif]-->
        <tr><td colspan="6">No tags are currently stored in the SABMiller database for this component</td></tr>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing this code my problem solved.

```
 <!--[if lte IE 8]>
     <style type="text/css" media="screen">
           table.outer_1 td { width:expression(450 + "px") !important; }
     </style> 
<![endif]-->

 <tr><td colspan="6">No tags are currently stored in the SABMiller database for this component</td></tr>
```